git ignore classess not ignore in intellij idea
I am using IntelliJ IDEA but when I want commit it shows all class file. Here is the image;

Here is the gitignore code...
        ELP.md
    target/
    !.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
    !**/src/main/**/target/
    !**/src/test/**/target/

    ### STS ###
    .apt_generated
    .classpath
    .factorypath
    .project
    .settings
    .springBeans
    .sts4-cache

    ### IntelliJ IDEA ###
    .idea
    *.iws
    *.iml
    *.ipr
    *.logs


    /logs/*
    /logs/
    ### NetBeans ###
    /nbproject/private/
    /nbbuild/
    /dist/
    /nbdist/
    /.nb-gradle/
    build/
    !**/src/main/**/build/
    !**/src/test/**/build/

    ### VS Code ###
    .vscode/

What is the reason to show class file...
Please help me...

Are you sure they are not in the git history? It flagging them as changed indicates they have been added already thus will not be ignored by git and so IntelliJ too

I assume you want to ignore the target/ directory. Your .gitignore is configured properly. As @randommm suggested, you must've already staged target/ directory before.
A simple fix would be to run:
git rm -r --cached .

This command removes everything from the index. You should no longer see the target/ directory in tracked files.
